# SQL Batch Data, Hope to find running time for each Status (minutes) based on Last Update Timestamps?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sequence, timing

Tickets can bounce in and out of statuses and need to be sure I capture the time in minutes that the ticket is in each status through the life cycle of the tickets.

**I did the statement below for each status, but will not get the proper time because of tickets bouncing in and out of statuses.**

```
SELECT t.ticket_number, 
MIN(update_date) start_time, MAX(update_date) stop_time,
DATEDIFF(second, min(update_date),max(update_date)) elapsed_sec 
FROM xxx.dbo.report t 
WHERE t.status= 'StopTime' 
GROUP BY t.ticket_number;
```

Statuses

*Closed, 
Complete,
New,
Waiting-1,
Waiting-2,
Waiting-3,
StopTime,
Research-1,
Research-2,
Resolved,
Special Request,
Opened Request,
Null*

This is completely new to me working with batch data..  What I'm looking for help with is a way to count in minutes, how long the ticket is in each status, as well as a running total at the end (if possible).

Sample Data:

```
'ticket_number  status  update_count    update_date
    156097  Stoptime    5               1/14/13 21:34
    164481  Stoptime    5               2/9/13 21:36
    164826  Stoptime    5               2/11/13 21:34
    165931  Stoptime    5               2/17/13 21:36
    177348  Stoptime    5               3/3/13 21:34
    179232  Stoptime    5               3/12/13 22:34
    181079  Stoptime    5               3/23/13 22:34
    258181  Stoptime    1               6/25/15 9:50
    257336  Stoptime    9               7/17/15 2:28
    245035  Closed      84              7/17/15 2:32
    259573  Closed      642             7/20/15 2:22
    245476  Closed      116             7/22/15 3:18
    251601  Closed      3               8/4/15 4:18
    251601  Closed      3               8/4/15 4:18
    259732  Closed      22              8/12/15 9:42
    264957  Closed      29              8/22/15 19:53'
```

Sample of Expected Output: *Ticket number is a distinct count of ticket number while the format of the metrics are in (mm:ss)  Thank you!  Reputation not up enough to post images, so could not fit all statuses on the expected output. My apologies.

```
Ticket  Closed  Complet New   Total Running Time (mm:ss)
156097  00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
164481  00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
164826  00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
165931  00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
177348  00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
179232  00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
181079  00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
245035  00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
245476  00:00   00:00   00:00   00:00
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: Sample/Expedted output is provided above.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query, it counts real time in each status and builds a report

```
WITH t AS (
    select 
        ticket_number,
        ISNULL(status,'null') status,
        update_date,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_number ORDER BY update_date) rn
    from xxx.dbo.report
), s AS (
    SELECT 
        t1.ticket_number,
        t1.status,
        t1.update_date,
        t2.update_date prevdate,
        case when t2.status=t1.status then DATEDIFF(s, t2.update_date, t1.update_date) end dif
    FROM t t1
    LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.ticket_number=t2.ticket_number AND t1.rn=t2.rn+1
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ticket_number,
        [status],
        cast(dateadd(s,sum(dif),0) as time(0)) [time]
    FROM s
    GROUP BY ticket_number,status )  src
PIVOT
(
  min([time])
  for [status] in ([Closed], [Complete], [New], [Waiting-1], [Waiting-2], [Waiting-3], [StopTime], [Research-1], [Research-2], [Resolved], [Special Request], [Opened Request], [null])
) piv
```

Comment: Dimitry!  I am forever in debt to you my friend!!  Thank you so much!  You are amazing!  How can I follow you on this page?

Comment: Dimitry, would there be a way to calculate add a few columns to get a total for 'working_time', and 'stoppage time'?  or even a running total?

Comment: And could you explain what you mean speaking about working and stoppage time? Is it based on kinds of statuses or is it a time ticket spends between statuses?

Comment: There are certain statuses that make the clock stop, for instance, waiting times, stoptime,

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for using [PIVOT/UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx). You could add a grouping on status and push the `AVG(calculated_minutes)` value out column wise using a pivot. Also, If you are familiar with SSRS then this would be a trivial report to throw together using column grouping.

**Update**

So you don't want to use PIVOT. You have to then do this manually using a sum of averages or sum of sum by ticket#. I typed this out here in this ticket and cannot guarantee that it will run, its the general concept you are searching.

```
SELECT
    ticket_number,  
    SumStatus1=SUM(SumStatus1),
    SumStatus2=SUM(SumStatus2),
    SumStatus3=SUM(SumStatus3),
    SumAll=SUM(SumaAll)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ticket_number,
        SumStatus1=CASE WHEN Status='status1' THEN elased_sec ELSE NULL END,
        SumStatus2=CASE WHEN Status='status2' THEN elased_sec ELSE NULL END,
        SumStatus3=CASE WHEN Status='status3' THEN elased_sec ELSE NULL EDN,
        SumaAll=elapsed_sec
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ticket_number,
            status,
            DATEDIFF(second, min(update_date),max(update_date)) elapsed_sec 
        FROM 
            report t
        GROUP BY 
            t.ticket_number,
            t.status    
    )AS A
)AS B
GROUP BY
    ticket_number
```

Comment: well, that seems a little too difficult given my lack of experience with batch data in SQL.  If there weren't so many rows, I could easily do this in excel.  The expected output does not have to be similar to that above, mainly looking for other suggestions on anyone who has had experience with this type of data.

Comment: Thank you lrb.  This is similar to what I'm searching for.  It appears that there should be a join in there somewhere.  Also, should there be a GROUP BY/ON etc.?  Thanks again -P

Comment: @Panthersfball234 I would go with this approach. Dynamic pivot would be another way to do what you need.

Comment: it doesn't seem do work.  Looks like it could be missing somehinng

Comment: the part where it says " )AS B

Comment: Hey, I added ticket_number to the first subquery A so that that field could be accessed in subquery B